# How to use LEDs to communicate using a UART

Tags: microcontroller, led, uart, photodiode, raspberry-pi-pico

I am using a UART to communicate between two [Raspberry Pi Picos](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-pico/), and want to use LED / photodiode pairs rather than wires.

I have two [SunLED XZMOK54W-8 610 nm LEDs](https://www.sunledusa.com/products/spec/XZMOK54W-8.pdf) paired with two [Advanced Photonix 019-141-411-R photodiodes](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Photonic%20Detetectors%20Inc%20PDFs/SD019-141-411-RGB_May7,2019.pdf). My UART1 TX pin is connected to one LED, and the corresponding photodiode is connected to UART1 RX on the other Pico via a [TI OPA4322SAIPW op-amp](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa4322.pdf). Vice versa for the other LED/photodiode pair. The grounds are connected as well.

I can see that the LEDs are transmitting data when I slow the baud rate on both devices down, but I'm not receiving data on the second Pico. My amp circuit is for my reverse bias diode, it outputs 3.3V in light and 0.6V in the dark. I think I need to wire it based on Jens answer below, where it outputs low voltage in light and 3.3V in the dark, to correspond to UART protocol. Here is my current circuit (LED based on Jens answer):
[image]

Here is my MicroPython code for each Pico, which worked when I had wires connected rather than LED/photodiodes:

Pico1:

```python
from machine import Pin, UART
import utime
#slowing baud rate way down to make sure the photodiode has a chance to respond
uart = UART(1,300)

while True:
    uart.write ("Working")
    utime.sleep(1)
```

Pico2:

```python
from machine import UART,Pin
uart = UART(1, 300)

while True:
    if uart.any():
        rcvChar = uart.read()
        print(rcvChar.decode("ascii"),end="")
```

Comment: @Justme Iv'e added a schematic, i'm very new to microcontrollers/uart, if this isn't possible to do would you mind explaining why?

Comment: Phototransistors are fast enough for (say) 9600 baud serial and can be connected more-or-less directly to the MCUs, so rather easier. In any case your  LEDs are shown backwards and TX should go to an LED on both, no part numbers on the comparators or op-amps so I'm not going to try to analyze those bits.

Comment: If your schematic is accurate then you have reversed TX and RX for U9. The TX output **always** connects to the LED.

Comment: Thank you @SpehroPefhany and @ Elliot Alderson, Iv'e updated my schematic to include part numbers and corrected the LED connections, I realized I accidentally flipped the TX and RX pins in my original schematic. This is my current setup, and it is still not receiving data, although I can see both LEDs lighting up and transmitting information

Comment: You’ve no pull-ups on the receivers  (maybe you’re using the micros’ built-in ones, and haven’t specified the values of the pull-down resistors.  You’ll need to make sure the micro inputs are going between valid logic high and low levels, so may need to adjust the resistor values to suit.  Perhaps try with DC levels to get this right and then try with low data rates and go from there.

Comment: This has nothing to do with microcontrollers or UARTs, but how to make photodiode amplifier. Would you explain why it is supposed to work, where did you get that circuit, or does it have a drawing error and it actually can work?

Comment: Why not use optocouplers? Also the photodiode amplifier schematic has the inputs swapped and the resistors in the wrong place.

Comment: @bobflux Ah, I had the opamp flipped in the schematic. I updated it again more carefully to reflect my actual setup. Ill look into optocouplers as well

Comment: @Justme This is my first time doing an amp circuit, and its very possible that it is wrong. It does work, it responds to my LED blinking just fine, but outputs a rather low voltage. It swings from ~0.18v to 0.3v when the LED is off vs on. I think the voltage output is so low that its not hitting the UART RX signal level

Comment: @Frog I messed around a bit with your idea earlier and couldn't find a way to use the internal UART RX pins, I tried pn = Pin(7, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP), which didn't seem to make a difference. I have such a quiet signal (0.3v) that the internal resistors might not be enough. I think I'll need an external pull-up resistor. It hasn't quite worked yet but im going to give it another go. Thanks for this tip!

Comment: If those are the voltages, then it can't work. Logic high level should be near supply voltage.

Comment: @Justme ah yeah Im getting pretty confident that is the issue then, I might need to rethink this opamp circuit to get a higher output voltage. Thank you for your help!

Comment: That photodiode has a color filter on it that drops its sensitivity to red light down to almost nothing, yet you have combined it with a red LED.  Almost any silicon photodiode would be a better choice than that one.  The opamp circuit also looks very strange to me.  Where did you find it?  Are you sure you weren't supposed to measure the photocurrent across the 500k resistor instead of the photodiode?

Comment: @user1850479 I think LED and Diode match close at 610 nm, at least this should be fine.

Comment: @Jens Look at the scale, not the shape of the plot. Responsivity is just 0.05 A/W.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple circuit for a start. Since UART signals of MCUs are idle high, I prefer to activate the LED if TX is low. Accordingly the OpAmp has a small offset voltage at IN+ and the output will only be low if the reverse current of the photo diode is high enough.

Ambient light introduces some current as well, so the threshold needs some adjustment via R4. This is a problem here, but a proper circuit to automatically adapt the threshold, needs much more components.

A true comparator would be better here, but the OPA4322 is already there and will do it.

I estimate this will work up to 19200 baud. Above that the value of R2 must be smaller, because it forms a low pass filter with the capacitance of the photo diode (about 25pF).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8Djs8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I tried this circuit with my op amp and got no response to light regardless of how I adjusted R4, although it did output around 1v consistently. Is it possible that the photodiodes responsiveness is too low? Using a voltmeter, I tested the photodiodes average response to my LED, and it swings from 0.05 to .25 on its own (not hooked up to any amplifier).

Comment: Since this OpAmp has no feedback circuit, it operates with very high open loop gain. So it can either output voltages close to 0 V or close to V+. If you measure 1 V with a multimeter, the OpAmp produces a square wave signal with 30% duty cycle and the multimeter integrates this. Other options: The OpAmp is dead or the MCU RX pin is accidentially configured as output with high level, fighting against the OpAmp.  Test the circuit without the diode and R4 with maximum resistance. The OpAmp must deliver a voltage close to V+.

Comment: Yes, you can connect the diode like a solar cell parallel to R2. This is another (forward) option to use it. Your measurement shows, that this is possible. Always verify voltages with the diode in darkness and with active ambient light - finally in combination with the TX LED.

Comment: I just replaced the opamp with a fresh one to make sure that wasn't the problem, and connected the circuit without the diode as you recommended. I connected the output to an ADC channel on the pico, and got a consistent 1.2v. Ive also double checked with some more experienced people to make sure my circuit followed your schematic, and confirmed I didn't make a simple mistake there. The -in opamp pin reads 3.3v, and the +in pin reads 0.29v, there should be a higher output from that Vdifference right? Id expect more like 3v rather than the 1.2v im getting

Comment: I would expect close to 0 V at IN-, not 3.3 V since R2 is connected to GND. Or did you replace the diode with a wire? I think, it's time for a question edit with layout informations and pictures, there are too many weird things.